# Customize shopify site so that every customer account must be approved by admin

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am building a shopify site and want that every customer account should be approved by the admin, so is there any app available for this or any other source through which this can be done.
I am new to liquid and shopify so please help me out to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in liquid, you'll need an app.

there is this app on that does it what you want:

https://apps.shopify.com/locksmith